# Why does my code return this error when I run it

Tags: vhdl

```vhdl
library IEEE; 

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all; 

entity LogicC is  

port(TL,TS,RL,GL,YL,TRX,CLK:in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);O:out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));

end entity; 

architecture DigitalS of LogicC is 

begin  

process(TL,TS,GL,YL,RL,TRX,O,CLK) 

begin 

if CLK = '1' and CLK'event then  

case O is 

when "000" => if TL='1'then O <= "000"; 

              elsif TL ='1' and TS = '0' and RL = '0' and TRX = '1' then O <= "001"; 

              end if; 

when "001" => if TL= '0' then O <= "001"; 

              elsif TL ='0' and TS = '1' and RL = '0' and TRX = '1' then O <= "011"; 

              end if; 

when "011" => if TS= '0' then O <= "011"; 

              elsif TL='0' and TS='1' or GL='1' and TRX= '1' then O <= "010"; 

              end if; 

when "010" => if TS='1' and YL='1' then O <= "010"; 

              elsif TL='1' and TS= '0' or YL='1' and TRX= '1' then O <= "100"; 

              end if; 

when "100" => if TS = '1' and RL= '1' then O <= "100"; 

              elsif TL='1' and TS='0' or RL= '0'  and TRX= '0' then O <= "101"; 

              end if; 

when "101" => if TL='0' and TS='0' or RL='0' and TRX='0' then O <= "111"; 

              elsif TL='1' and RL='1' then O <= "101"; 

              end if; 

when "111" => if TL= '1' and GL='1' then O <= "111"; 

              elsif TL='0' and TS='0' or GL= '1' and TRX = '0' then "110"; 

              end if; 

when "110" => if TL='0' and TS='1' then O <= "110"; 

              elsif TL='1' and TS='0' or YL='1' and TRX='0' then "000"; 

              end if; 

end case; 

end if; 

end process; 

end architecture DigitalS of LogicC;
```

I tried to put it in a VHDL tool to try it and fix any errors in the code, but I keep ending up with the same thing:

> Line 77 Col 27: unexpected 'o' expecting "--", "/*", ';', or white
> space

when I try to run it. Any suggestions on how to fix my code will be helpful.

Comment: The same lack of parentheses to separate different short circuit operators shows up on lines 77, 83, 89, 93, 101 and 107 after prepending 41 lines to your code shown. Lines 101 and 107 should have assignment targets e.g. ...then O <= "110";. The end statement for the architecture can't contain "of LogicC". Your port clause declares CLK as std_logic_vector (all inputs should be std_logic, output O should be std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) After adding Tricky's missing choice `when others =>` your code will compile and run. Requires -2008 to evaluate output O. What VHDL tool produced the error?

Comment: A process only containing signal assignments conditional on a clock edge only needs to have the clock in the process sensitivity list. It'll evaluate the sensitivity list for every signal event of any signal found within it.

Answer (score 0):

`and` and `or` operators have the same precedence. So when you have something like this:

```vhdl
elsif TL='0' and TS='1' or GL='1' and TRX= '1' then
```

it the compiler doesnt know if you meant this:

```vhdl
elsif (TL='0' and TS='1') or (GL='1' and TRX= '1') then
```

or this

```vhdl
elsif TL='0' and (TS='1' or GL='1') and TRX= '1' then
```

So you need to clarify to the compiler which one you meant.

There are other issues:

- Your case statement doesnt cover all possible options. I suggest a `when others =>` case.
- `end architecture digitalS`, you cannot have `of logicC`